# Adding non geographic data from MSSQL Database to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, sql-server, database

In QGIS (2.8) I am trying to add non-geometric data / flat data that originates in a MS SQL database. This flat data later should be joined with other layers etc.

Connecting to the specific database = working
Listing the table that I would like to open up in QGIS = working

When adding the selected 'flat' table I get the following error message:

```
dbname='data' host=server\sql2008 table="dbo"."TABLE" sql= is an invalid layer - not loaded
```

Is there a "trick" or a set of conditions that the table needs to meet before it can be added into QGIS as "flat" data?

Answer (score 2):

It apears QGIS is looking for atleast one integer value in the data.
The solution consists of creating a view based on the original table including an extra col:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Outlet Code] DESC) AS Row
```

This view can than be added in QGIS using the method described earlier.

It might be interesting to know how one could tell QGIS that this data is containing X/Y coordinates for later use.